# Hyperledger fabric chaincode: function calling another function from within chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have a scenario where I need to call a some other(say query) function from a chaincode function (say update). Does hyperledger fabric provide any interface for this.
Eg:

```
   ...
    async query(stub, args) {
    }
    async update(stub, args) {
      if(condition) {
        call query();
      }
    }
    ...
```

I have tried the answer on following post but it did't work.
[how to invoke chaincode function from itself to record sub transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808793/how-to-invoke-chaincode-function-from-itself-to-record-sub-transactions).
Though by using invokeChaincode() I am able to call function from another chaincode.

Thanks in advance.

Chaincode code:

```
    let Chaincode = class {

    async Init(stub) {
        return shim.success();
    }

    async Invoke(stub) {

        let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();

        console.info(ret);

        let method = this[ret.fcn];

        if (!method) {
            throw new Error('Received unknown function ' + ret.fcn + ' invocation');
        }
        try {
            let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
            return shim.success(payload);
        } catch (err) {
            return shim.error(err);
        }
    }

    async init(stub, args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new Error('Invalid args. Expects no args');
        }
    }

    async query(stub, args) {
        ...
    }

    async dummy(stub, args) {
        return Buffer.from('Hello');
    }


    async update(stub, args) {
    ...
        let resp = await dummy(); // gives error
        //let resp = await stub.invokeChaincode('cc2', ['dummy'] );  // working
        console.log(resp)
    ...
    }    
};
shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As noted by @kartik-chauhan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63162786/2787288), this approach is useful if you are using `fabric-contract-api`. Follow his answer if you are using `fabric-shim`.

Maybe a bit late for OP but for anyone else interested you can call another function from a function of the same chaincode by using `this.<another_function>`.

We have been using the [IBM Blockchain Platform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform) for VSCode and it has a kind of wizard to generate a chaincode in GO, javascript and typescript. The following is an excerpt of the chaincode generated for javascript where you can observe how function myAssetExists is called from function createMyAsset via `this.myAssetExists`:

```
const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class MyAssetContract extends Contract {

    async myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId) {
        const buffer = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        return (!!buffer && buffer.length > 0);
    }

    async createMyAsset(ctx, myAssetId, value) {
        const exists = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} already exists`);
        }
        const asset = { value };
        const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(asset));
        await ctx.stub.putState(myAssetId, buffer);
    }
...
```

Comment: Is this worked for only boolean or for the buffer object also. I am getting error here when return buffer. The Error is: Calling chaincode Invoke() returned. Because i thought it's return the context also.

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative approach I am installing and instantiating same chaincode with two names say cc1 and cc2 on same channel say ch1. Then I am using:

```
 invokeChaicode('cc2', ['function', 'arg1', arg2]);
```

from chaincode one (cc1).

But the problem is I need to install and instantiate same chaincode twice with different names on same channel.

Any other insights are welcome.

Comment: Why not just call the second function by name directly from the first function?

Comment: OK will try that. I never thought this way. :) Sometimes we miss simpler scenarios.

Comment: I declared a dummy function as: `async dummy(stub, args) { return Buffer.from('hello'); }` and called it from another function (say update) like: `async update(stub, args) { console.log(await dummy()); } `and got the following error: Error: Error endorsing invoke: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: dummy is not defined - <nil>

Comment: would you mind posting a larger sample of your chaincode?

Comment: @GariSingh appended the larger code sample to question.

Answer (score 0):

@jama's answer to the question is correct. However, it is specific to `fabric-contract-api`. For people who are using `fabric-shim` package can implement the same by passing `this` in the method which is to be invoked. e.g.

```
async Invoke(stub) {
    console.info('Transaction ID: ' + stub.getTxID());
    console.info(util.format('Args: %j', stub.getArgs()));

    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);

    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
        console.log('no function of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
        throw new Error('Received unknown function ' + ret.fcn + ' invocation');
    }

    try {
        let payload = await method(stub, ret.params, this);
        return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return shim.error(err);
    }
}
```

One only needs to pass `this` in the `await method()` to provide the current class's context to the invoked method.

The method which has to call another method from inside it has to accept `this` as one of the arguments e.g.

```
async getMarblesByRange(stub, args, thisClass) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
    }

    let startKey = args[0];
    let endKey = args[1];

    let resultsIterator = await stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);
    let method = thisClass['getAllResults'];
    let results = await method(resultsIterator, false);

    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(results));
}

async getAllResults(iterator, isHistory) {
...
}
```

In the above code-snippet, `thisClass` is passed as an argument in the `getMarblesByRange` method, using which the method calls another method `getAllResults()`.

The method can be called either using `thisClass['getAllResults']` or simply `thisClass.getAllResults`.

All the code-snippets have been taken from [marble chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/marbles02/javascript/marbles_chaincode.js).

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling coders using "fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi" in chaincode.

```
func (s *SmartContract) ChangeCarOwner(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, carNumber string, newOwner string) error {
    car, err := s.QueryCar(ctx, carNumber)
...
}

func (s *SmartContract) QueryCar(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, carNumber string) (*Car, error) {
...
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes we should think it more simple.Well, the answer is: call it directly.
For example:
we got two functions A and B

```
func (s *SmartContract) A(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {}
```

```
func (s *SmartContract) B(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {}
```

if we want to call function A within function B,just do it as

```
func (s *SmartContract) B(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {

 s.A(APIstub,args)

}
```

Comment: OP's chaincode is written in javascript. It'd be better to post a solution for the same.